# Show that a semigroup is semisimple iff $A^2 = A$ for every two-sided ideal $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup, a subset $I\subseteq S$ is called an ideal if $SI \subseteq I$ and $IS \subseteq S$. We denote by $S^1$ the semigroup $S$ adjoined with a identity if it does not contains one, and for $a \in S$ we set $J(a) = S^1aS^1$, the principal ideal generated by $a$. Also we set for $a,b \in S$
$$
  a \mathcal J b :\Leftrightarrow S^1 a S^1 = S^1 b S^1.
$$
For an ideal we can form the [Rees factor semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rees_factor_semigroup) denotes by $S / I$, which essentially means collapsing everything in $I$ to a zero in the factor semigroup. Denote the $\mathcal J$-equivalence class of some $a \in S$ by $J_a$.

A principal factor is a factor semigroup of the form $J(a) / (J(a) \setminus J_a)$, see the [Ecyclopdia of mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Principal_factor). The unique minimal ideal, called the kernel of $S$, is among the principal factors.

A null semigroup (or semigroup with zero multiplication) is a semigroup $S$ with a zero $0 \in S$ such that $ab = 0$ for all $a,b \in S$. A semigroup is called *semisimple* if none of the principal factors is a null semigroup.

> I want to show that a semigroup $S$ is semisimple if and onyl if $A^2 = A$ for every ideal $A \subseteq S$.

This is an exercise from the book *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory* by J. Howie, page 95.

What I do not understand is that if a semigroup contains a zero $0$, then the minimal ideal must be $\{0\}$, in particular this is a null semigroup. But I can very well find semigroups such that $A^2 = A$ for every ideal that have a zero. For example take any group $G$, adjoin a zero $0$ by setting $g0 = 0g =0$ and observe that the only ideals are $\{0\}$ and $G \cup\{0\}$ itself, and they both fulfill the condition on ideals...

So any hints on this exercise, or what I have understood wrong here?

*EDIT*: Maybe there is a typo in the exercise, and just the principal factors not equal to the kernel are meant. But the same exercise appears in the classic *Algebraic Theory of Semigroups* by Clifford/Preston, and the above link to the Encyclopedia does not excludes the kernel. But if we exclude the kernel, than $A^2 = A$ for every ideal $A$ iff no principal factor not equal the kernel is null. For $A^2 \subsetneq A$ choose $a \in A \setminus A^2$, then $J(a) / N(a)$ is null, for if $x,y \in J(a)$ with $xy \notin N(a)$ would imply $a = u(xy)v$ for some $u,v \in S^1$ and $(ux)(yv) \in A^2$. Conversely,
as $S^2 / I = (S/I)^2$ for every semigroup $S$ and ideal $I$ we have that $(J(a)/N(a))^2 = J(a)^2 / N(a) = J(a) / N(a)$ and as $|J(a)/N(a)| > 1$ if $N(a) \ne\emptyset$ those principal factors not equal the kernel are not null. But in case is is not a typo I ask for feedback/clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clifford and Preston give the following definition:

> A semigroup is *semisimple* if every of its principal factors is
>   $0$-simple or simple.

This is the right definition and it makes the exercise correct since the semigroup $0$ is simple.

Unfortunately, Howie modified the definition, leading to a wrong statement. The same wrong definition (and the same exercise) have been copied and pasted in Higgins' book *Techniques of semigroup theory*.

Comment: Thanks. And as the kernel is always simple and the only simple principal factor, its the same formulation as if we exclude the kernel, i.e. the solution in my edit should be the correct one.